# c#: Actions incomparable?

Tags: c#, comparison, action

I'm trying to compare two Actions. The comparison with == always returns false as does the Equals-method even though it's the same instance.

My question is: Is it really not possible or am I doing it wrong?

Cheers
AC

Comment: Can you post the code where you obtain these two actions that "are the same instance"? I believe you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**You are doing it wrong.**

If I am to believe you, when you say "even though it's the same instance", then the following code executed through [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) tells me that you must be doing something wrong, or the "same instance" is incorrect:

```
void Main()
{
    Action a = () => Debug.WriteLine("test");
    Action b = a;

    (a == b).Dump("==");
    (a.Equals(b)).Dump("Equals");
    object.ReferenceEquals(a, b).Dump("ReferenceEquals");
}
```

The output is:

```
== 
True 

Equals 
True 

ReferenceEquals 
True
```

In other words, both `==`, `a.Equals(b)` and `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` says its the same instance.

On the other hand, if I duplicate the code:

```
Action a = () => Debug.WriteLine("test");
Action b = () => Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

Then they all report false.

If I link them both to a named method, and not an anonymous one:

```
void Main()
{
    Action a = Test;
    Action b = Test;

    (a == b).Dump("==");
    (a.Equals(b)).Dump("Equals");
    object.ReferenceEquals(a, b).Dump("ReferenceEquals");
}

private static void Test()
{
}
```

Then the output is:

```
== 
True 

Equals 
True 

ReferenceEquals 
False
```

In other words, I now got two `Action` instances, not just one, but they still compare equal.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `Method` and `Target` properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `action.Method` and `action.Target`.

Comment: OK, they could be different then! If you just need to check the method, ignore the target and just compare the `Method`